# Unexpected results when subtracting two time values

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

This is really strange. I have two time values.

First time:

```
$t1 = 1311165885;
```

Second time (which is bigger than the first time):

```
$t2 = 1312049530;
```

I am going to subtract the times like this:

```
$diff = $t2-$t1;
```

When I do an `echo $diff` this is coming out:

```
echo 'Time_diff: ' . $diff; 
Time_diff: -1311163874
```

The actual result should be `883645`. What is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Craphunter

Then here is my code:

```
<?php 
$current_time = DataConverter::makeDatetime();

foreach ($order as $list) {
    echo '-----------'.'</br>';
    $create_unix_time = DataConverter::makeTimestamp($list->getCreate());
    $diff = $current_time-$create_unix_time;

    if ($diff >= 864000) {
        echo 'aus db: ' .  $list->getErstellt() . '</br>';
        echo $list->getId() . '</br>';
        echo 'old';
    }
    else {
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: -1, because you don't show us the code that is producing your result.

Comment: Are you running on a 32 or 64 Bit system? Which PHP Version? Sounds a bit like an Integer overflow to me, although PHP _should_ catch that and turn it into a float.

Comment: 64Bit, PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.5 Thanks to Michael Stum!

And sorry, but I am a newbee in programming and I cannot help very well these question here.

Comment: What is DataConverter? Is it something public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$t1 = 1311165885;
$t2 = 1312049530;
$diff = $t2-$t1;

echo 'Time 1: ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t1) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Tim2 2: ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t2) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Time diff: ' . $diff . PHP_EOL;
```

... prints this:

```
Time 1: 2011-07-20 14:44:45
Tim2 2: 2011-07-30 20:12:10
Time diff: 883645
```

What you say you are getting does look like a regular timestamp rather than a diff:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1311163874) . PHP_EOL;
```

... prints:

```
2011-07-20 14:11:14
```

There's probably a mistyped variable name somewhere in your code.

Comment: yes thanks man! it  was a mistyped variable type! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I ignore the data type result of method DataConverter::makeTimestamp. Maybe that is a wrong assumption suppose the result is integer. Maybe.
But, you can force the data type to integer and test if that is the problem.

```
$current_time = intVal( DataConverter::makeDatetime() );
```

and

```
$create_unix_time = intVal( DataConverter::makeTimestamp( $list->getCreate() ) );
```